How to deal with accounting hell because of multiple currencies/countries involved?
I am from India. I live in Europe and I earn from US as a freelancer.
I have so many accounts and I don't know what to do

USD business account - Receive money from clients

USD personal account - For personal expenses

Another USD personal account - My usual personal USD accounts blocks transfer to crypto exchanges

EUR personal account - For local transactions where USD account doesn't work

INR personal account - For personal transactions in India and to fund Indian broker

Another INR personal account - The other INR account have problem receiving funds from USD bank account, so this account just receive the money and route it to other INR account


Apart from this, there are multiple broker account and credit cards.
I have a google sheet where I add balance in each account every month. This way, I am aware of my net worth. I also have another sheet where I add invoices payment received.
But, I have no way to track my expense because money flows in random direction all the time. There is no single account. My net worth fluctuate with stock market so it's even harder to track expenses
What should I do?

It might help to decide which is your main operating currency and track everything with that in mind. Some tools, like GnuCash, allow having different currencies for different accounts, and track conversion rates either manually or automatically.

Have you considered to use a proper bookkeeping software like GNU Cash?

@littleadv Will it solve the problem of fluctuation in net worth because of stocks movement every month?

@Philipp Will it solve the problem of fluctuation in net worth because of stocks movement every month?

If you own stocks, then you net worth will widely fluctuate just as the stock prices will.  You can not solve that with some accounting trick. The only solution is to sell the stocks and put that money into a more stable form of investment. But that's probably not what you want.

@Philipp But how do I track it? Are there other solutions?
Right now, I use formulas in google sheet to calculate monthly P/L and adjust the expenses accordingly

How important exactly is tracking your stock portfolio to you? Are you investing in stocks like a regular person - buying them and letting them sit until you need money - or are you day-trading with the intention of profiting from every small price fluctuation?

@Philipp I don't day trade but tracking fluctuation is quite important. Reason is every month, I count how much money I have in each bank and current portfolio value to determine my net worth. Then I subtract it with last month to determine change in net worth. Then I subtract my income to calculate the expense. If my portfolio falls 9000 USD in one month, suddenly my expense are 11,000. That's why I want to track unrealized p/l so I can calculate my actual expense as 2000 USD.

I want to track my net worth every month, monthly income and monthly expenses.

I posted an answer that is hopefully helpful to you. If my answer doesn't answer your question completely, please comment on that answer.

Personal finance/accounting software often includes the ability to automatically download and track stock quotes., along with reporting and charting net worth.

Why do you need to track your net worth so closely? If you let go of the need to have this information, it seems you would lose some administrative stress, as well.

@Grade'Eh'Bacon Why? It's so easy to check. I just current balance in all broker + current portfolio value. Take barely 10-15 minute in a month. Calculating expense is the hardest part because money flows through multiple account (sometime in circle)

I don't understand what you mean by 'expenses'. I understand that there is cash coming in and out of multiple accounts, but that's different than "expenses" which are actual amounts paid during the month. Typically, you would track expenses against a budget of what you planned to spend. If you don't have specific decisions to make based on all this reporting, it might just be naval-gazing. For example - you mention stocks going up and down as impacting your expense tracking, in the last 2 sentences. These things are unrelated.

@Grade'Eh'Bacon Expenses are anything I spend. All I want to do is track my how much I spending every month and what are the major expenses. I do so by https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/163512/how-to-deal-with-accounting-hell-because-of-multiple-currencies-countries-involv?noredirect=1#comment337179_163512 .

Suppose I spend 10,000 USD which is way more than usual expense. Now I want to find what did I spend it on. This part is really hard.

@codepanda: Then solve it in code. Get or write a personal finance package which can automagically download your current account balances, including your brokerage account balances and current equity quotes, and that can handle summarizing across the currencies you use. Update as frequently as desired. Done.  I am deliberately not recommending a specific tool;  I don't deal with multiple currencies.

Personal finance tools also make it easy to track your spending.

@keshlam I am using google sheets for that. I only add net worth, credit, monthly P/L to it. Then I end up with 11,000 USD expense in 1 month sometime. It's hard to investigate that. I don't know any tool that deal with multiple currency + stock portfolio at same time

If you're going to build your own spreadsheets you are going to have to build your own solutions for this. If you want a can ed solution, use a personal finance package where someone else has already done that work. Gnu Cash should be able to do much or all if it, if you are willing to accept its double-entry-bookkeeping data model. Others probably can, but I haven't had reason to investigate. Though I consider doing so every year when Quicken wants their renewal fee.

When you are regularly doing business in different currencies, then it can make sense to track your income, expenses and net worth in each currency separately.
That means your bookkeeping would have one book for USD, one book for EUR and one book for INR, each one with a separate balance, a separate income and expense flow and a separate monthly budget. Each of those books would then have a sub-account for each actual account denoted in that currency (personal bank account, business bank account, credit card, etc.).
That way you avoid chaos due to currency fluctuations. Calculating your net worth according to the current exchange rates might be interesting, but is probably not actually that important or meaningful. Exchange rates rarely reflect the true purchasing power of each currency anyway. Exchange rates fluctuate. And you want to avoid buying one currency with another as much as possible, because that usually means you pay conversion fees. Which means that tracking 3 net-worths in 3 different currencies is probably more meaningful than trying to calculate one net-worth in one currency.
OK, but what if you notice that one of these books has a negative monthly cash-flow, which you can't get positive without taking money in another currency? Then you have to bite the bullet and convert currency from one to another whenever you are about to get bankrupted. This would appear as an expense in the book of currency A and as an income in the book of currency B. If you have to do that regularly, then it might be useful to consider this a monthly income/expense in your respective budgets. But keep in mind that currency exchange rates change, so you have to make sure the numbers are still accurate.
When it comes to stocks, real estate, cars and other non-cash assets you own: There is a reason why business bookkeeping separates the tracking of current assets from that of fixed assets. It's usually not useful to treat such assets as if they were cash. Why? Because you can't pay for groceries by cutting off a piece of your car. While you could theoretically sell those assets at any time, in practice you are not going to do that because you need those assets, finding a buyer and executing the trade will take time and effort or the current market situation makes it a bad time to sell them. Well, maybe you could get a loan backed by one of those assets to temporarily turn them into liquid cash, but such loans usually come with conditions that make them attractive to only the thoughtless or the desperate.
Which means you might want to keep those assets in separate fixed asset accounts and update the value of these assets perhaps once a year to account for deprecation and stock price changes.

Thanks for the detailed answer. I think I have to read more about current assets and fixed assets
